# ReferenceField in mongoengine

Tags: python, django, mongoengine

I use mongoengine with django. I have two applications with models.

`app1/models.py`:

```
from mongoengine import fields
from mongoengine.document import Document

class Model1(Document):
    name = fields.StringField()
    lists = fields.ListField(fields.ReferenceField("Model2", dbref=False))
```

`app2/models.py`:

```
from mongoengine import fields
from mongoengine.document import Document

class Model2(Document):
    name = fields.StringField()
```

All applications were added to `INSTALLED_APPS`. When I use the django dev-server, everything is fine. But using this code with uwsgi-server there is an error:

```
Model2 has not been registered in the document registry.
Importing the document class automatically registers it, has it
been imported?
```

What I should do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should import `app2.models` somewhere. Put a comment by the import saying why it's there, so nobody removes the useless-looking import in the future.

When the django dev server starts up it imports the models from all installed apps and validates them.  You'll see

```
Validating models... 
0 errors found
```

This does not happen in a production environment. It is just a nicety of the dev server.

Comment: Yes! I imported all my models in `__init__` and this works, thank you.